# create-react-app with sass not loading styles

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to add sass/scss support to [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html).

So I did these steps:

1. `npm eject`
2. `npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev`
3. Opned the webpack.config.dev.js file and added this to loaders section:

   ```
   {
       test: /\.scss$/,
       loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
   },
   ```

In my app.js file i reference an scss file: `import './css/app.scss';`

When i run `npm start` everything compiles with no errors but the application loads with no styling.

What am i missing?

Comment: you missed `include: paths.appSrc`

Comment: @TheReason - I tried with and without it, didn't help either way

Comment: Did you follow [this comment](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/e7d71bd574b893ebace06b8111d20fcd466d5d69/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L117-L121) and add a line to `exclude`?

Comment: @DanAbramov - Thanks Dan, it worked! How about you write it as an answer so i can mark it as true?

Comment: I had this issue coming from an older version of `react-scripts` using `node-sass-chokidar`. I was able to get it working by deleting the old autogenerated `.css` files and uninstalling `node-sass-chokidar` and `npm-run-all`. After, I ran `npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev`. Then, I ran `npm start` and it output file path errors in the console, which I was able to resolve quickly with using the [CRA style docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet). Then, it all worked fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just went through this, and seems that there are lot of people lost or not finding the right answer. This is what I did:

#### Get control over the configuration

`npm run eject`

Running this command will copy all the configuration files and the transitive dependencies (Webpack, Babel, ESLint, etc) right into your project, as you noted all that was inside a npm module called react-script. Do not modify this package directly!

#### Install sass compiler and webpack loader

`npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev`

At this point you have to install the sass compiler and the webpack loader as development dependencies.

#### Modify the webpack configuration

1. Open `config\webpack.config.dev.js`.
2. Add `/\.scss$/,` to the exclude array in the url loader, it will look something like this after the update:

   ```
   exclude: [
       /\.html$/,
       /\.(js|jsx)$/,
       /\.css$/,
       /\.json$/,
       /\.svg$/,
       /\.scss$/, //Add this line
   ],
   ```
3. Add the SASS/SCSS loader:

   ```
   {
       test: /\.scss$/,
       loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
   },
   ```

Comment: @BrunoQuaresma, maybe if you share a more detailed explanation I could help :)

Comment: I reseted the file, followed the instructions again and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: You can add sourceMap support:
`loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'postcss' ,'sass?sourceMap']`

Comment: at development this makes load sass files in <style> tags and build will not include styles at all.

Comment: Modern official solution: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck with the same problem reading it's [documentations](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet).

Unitl I found that the README.md file inside the created project with create-react-app has documented it in another way and it worked. I think relying on that readme file ( that is shipped with your created project ) is better option.

Answer (score 1):

## Styling using Sass without Ejecting

### 1) Install Koala

[Koala](http://koala-app.com/) is a sass, less etc.. compiler. You can use any tools of your choice for this.

### 2) Add your src folder

Add the source folder containing all your SCSS files to Koala. It will monitor for any modification to your Sass files and generate the compiled CSS version instantly.

### 3) Refer to the CSS files

Use the CSS file generated by Koala directly your project.

```
import './style.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

```
npm run eject
```

Now the config files will be shown in the project folder

**Step 2:**
Install sass compiler and webpack loader

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev
```

In **config\webpack.config.dev.js**
add **/.scss$/** to the **exclude** array

**Step 3:**
Add below loader in the **rules** array (should be added before file-loader)

```
  {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              require.resolve('css-loader'),
              require.resolve('sass-loader')
            ]
  }
```

And start your application.

You can rename your existing css files to scss and work

Comment: never eject - use customize cra etc

Answer (score -1):

```js
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass','scss']   //add 'scss'
},
```